# Error with MySQL Rollback

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to execute a command to list the total sales by customer and by product, with subtotals by
customer and a grand total for all product sales in MySQL database using Microsoft SQL server management studio but I am getting a strange error.

Here is the exact code I am using:

> SELECT CUS_CODE, P_CODE, SUM(SALE_UNITS*SALE_PRICE) AS TOTSALES
>
> FROM DWDAYSALESFACT NATURAL JOIN DWCUSTOMER
>
> GROUP BY CUS_CODE, P_CODE WITH ROLLUP;

and my error messages are:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'.
>
> Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: i dont think you can connect to mysql with ssms

Comment: You are not specifying the keys to join on, e.g. JOIN DWCUSTOMER ON customberId = customerRef

Comment: any suggestions on how i would SPECIFY the keys

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ROLLUP you can't also use an ORDER BY clause. That is what is throwing the error.

Comment: when i changed my code to `SELECT CUS_CODE, P_CODE, SUM(SALE_UNITS*SALE_PRICE) AS TOTSALES
FROM DWDAYSALESFACT NATURAL JOIN DWCUSTOMER
GROUP CUS_CODE, P_CODE WITH ROLLUP;
`  I still get the same error